# Can't get event target data attribute when inside aura:if tag

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura

I'm trying to get the value of a data attribute from a button calling a client side controller. However, when the button is inside an aura:if tag, it's not working:

**Component**

```
<aura:if isTrue="true">
    <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" type="button" onclick="{!c.showMeMyAttribute}" id="myAwesomeId" data-customattribute="HelloWorld">Click me please!</button>
</aura:if>
```

**Controller**

```
showMeMyAttribute : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log('id: ' + event.srcElement.id);
    console.log('customattribute: ' + event.currentTarget.dataset.customattribute);
}
```

In this case, dataset is undefined.
I also tried using srcElement, but id is undefined too.

However, with aura:renderIf it's working fine, but as it's deprecated I guess it should be working with aura:if too.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue that that we're working on. Please open a case to track and tell them to link to the internal work item W-3206803.

Comment: Fix is scheduled to be released in the next week or so in the .12 patch.

Comment: Thanks for the update Trevor. As you said, I created a Case, and they gave me the link to the known issue which is here: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A00000183rMQAQ

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it would indeed seem that Lightning Locker treats the body of that `aura:if` as belonging to another namespace so the DOM elements are not visible.

So while I would definitely classify this as needing a fix, in this use case it could easily be worked around. You don't need the button to cease to exist completely under your condition, just to hide it. So you could use conditional classes:

```
<button class="{!'slds-button slds-button--brand' + if(v.someBoolean, '', ' sdls-hide')}" 
type="button" onclick="{!c.showMeMyAttribute}" id="myAwesomeId" 
data-customattribute="HelloWorld">Click me please!</button>
```